# Using jQuery/bootstrap/zurb foundation to create desktop-like application?

Tags: jquery, css, html, web-services, qt

Is there any simple framework for creating classic desktop-like applications? I'm talking about achieving the look and feel of desktop apps (Windows/Mac/GNU/Linux) using existing JS/CSS frameworks.

I tried Bootstrap and zurb, but the page still feels more like a website.

I need to make it just like it would look like if I used GTK, Qt, etc.

Comment: Can describe _"but the page still feels more like a website"_ ?

Comment: It lacks the toolbars and icons and all that dirrefernt stuff. I can sure style it myself, but I don't want to reinvent a wheel. I'd like to just create menubar and individual toolbars and assign IconButtons to it.

Comment: Is _"like to just create menubar and individual toolbars and assign IconButtons to it"_ not effectively same as _"can style style it myself,"_ ? See http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/ , http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/GTK+3+Theme+Template?content=142117

Comment: I think JavaScript bindings for Qt Widgets are possible, but how do you imagine using CSS? Qt supports basic CSS styling of separate widgets, but it's hardly possible to transform HTML+CSS layout to Qt Widgets layout.